# Python 3. Проблема с модулем VLC

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, vlc

Пытаюсь импортировать модуль vlc, в итоге выходит ошибка:

input:

```
>>> import vlc
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 207, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\vlc.py", line 167, in find_lib
    dll = ctypes.CDLL(libname)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Не найден указанный модуль
```

Сразу скажу: vlc установлен, в библиотеке смотрел. Не могу понять конкретно, какой модуль не может найти мой змей или в чём конкретно ошибка. Что делать?

Заранее благодарен

Comment: Что значит _"vlc установлен"_? Вы про бинарный файл `exe` говорите или про модуль для `Python`? Нужно и то и другое.

Comment: Благодарю. Пишите ответ, я отмечу как решённый.

p.s. https://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.8/win64/vlc-2.2.8-win64.exe vlc  скачан тут

Comment: На будущее: установите `ipython`, будет намного проще тестовые примеры делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`vlc`](https://pypi.org/project/python-vlc/) - это модуль-обёртка для [плеера VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.ru.html).

Поэтому для его работы также необходимо установить сам плеер.
Скачать Вы его можете с [официального сайта](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.ru.html):

(Windows x32): https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.7.1/win32/vlc-3.0.7.1-win32.exe